# Prevalence of 64bit vs 32bit platforms

Tags: linux, windows, 32bit-64bit

I am in the process of making precompiled binaries for some libraries. In terms of the major platforms, anybody have any data on the prevalence of 32bit vs 64bit for Windows, Linux, and MacOS?

Clarification: I am looking for something like this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems

But with breakdowns of 32bit vs 64bit

Comment: That's a little broad. Are you talking globally, or just North America, or just one city. Also, corporate vs consumer? Primary age groups?

Comment: @gibberish Mainly, I am interested in finding out if I make only 64bit binaries, what percentage of people won't be able to run my software.

Comment: What kind of libraries?  Is it really that much of a burden to provide two builds?  In my experience it is pretty trivial (assuming you don't have portability issues, of course).

Comment: My approach is to only offer 32-bit builds for Windows and Mac, since they can run them without problems due to excellent 32-bit support on 64-bit systems. On Linux, I provide both 32-bit as well as 64-bit builds, because some 64-bit Linux distros don't have good 32-bit support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, 64 bit has been available since at least windows xp. However, it was not popular. I would call it a safe guess 99% of all xp systems out there are 32 bit. Why? You did not need 64 bit back then because systems did not have enough RAM to justify a different OS. By the time windows 7 arrived, RAM prices dropped to a point that 2 or more gb of RAM was mainstream. Computer manufacturers picked up on this and stated deploying 64 bit by default.

So the rule thumb is that windows xp is almost always 32 bit, and windows 7 is typically 64. That leaves vista dangling in the middle, but lucky for us, very few people run vista today.

I have seen recent popularity figures for xp to be of the order of 30%, so both 32 and 64 are strong.

**Edit:** According to [this Microsoft blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2010/07/08/64-bit-momentum-surges-with-windows-7.aspx), the picture for windows 7 is less black-and-white than I painted it above: 3 years ago, windows 7 64 bit penetration was only 46%. The article does note that on newly bought computers, 64 bit was dominant. I feel safe to assume that a large majority of Windows 7 machines today are 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

It currently doesn't show Linux, but I will often use Steam's HW report to get basic numbers for things like this. Among other things, it will show you the percentage of Windows and Mac 64-bit usage.

http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/

Granted, the audiences is going to be skewed toward the gamer market, but you didn't constrain the question to what audience you are interested in.

Comment: Here's a [more representative sample](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2010/07/08/64-bit-momentum-surges-with-windows-7.aspx) from the horse's mouth.  That's from 3 years ago so it's almost certainly more weighted towards 64-bit now, but 32-bit probably still holds a not insignificant chunk of the market (especially due to XP, which still has something like a 35% market share).